# How to resize an image

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to resize an image that I get from my camera gallery to fit the ImageView in another activity. I am getting the image. I just need to know how to resize it to fit the ImageView.

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 0);
 }
 });
}
protected void putExtras(Bundle bundle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
     }}}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
```

my xml

```
         <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_margin="3dp"
         android:layout_weight=".1"
         android:background="@drawable/greenline" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question only makes sense if the ImageView has a defined size the image can be fitted to. When you set the layout_width to wrap_content then it's exactly the other way round. The ImageView would wrap around the image and that doesn't seem to be what you want. So you need to use match_parent for both layout_width, layout_height or specify a concrete size like 30dip or such. Once you have that you can use android:scaleType as others mentioned.

So change your ImageView to something like this:

```
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent "
         android:layout_height="match_parent "
         android:scaleType="center"
         android:layout_margin="3dp"
         android:layout_weight=".1"
         android:background="@drawable/greenline" />
```

Which scaleType you use depends on how the image should be fitted to the ImageView, with or without scaling and cropping etc.

Comment: It works for the width but not height. I must be doing something wrong. I'll come back to this later.

Comment: If you elaborate on the "doesn't work for the height" I could possibly give you some advice

Comment: Im have lots of TextViews and buttons in a TableRow and. image1 is just one small View. I have every button and Table set to match_parent . The width of the pic is just like I want it but the height is way too big

Comment: match_parent will just fill the available height. If no other element takes that space then the ImageView will. So you have to think about the design of that screen. A good design works on different screen sizes and orientation and that's something really hard to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `android:scaleType` attribute to the ImageView. More details can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() if doing it programatically